# SonarQube plugin unable to install in RAD 9.0

Tags: sonarqube, ibm-rad, sonarlint

I installed SonarQube plugin in RAD 9.0 from http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/
(Help > Install New Software > Added SonarQube Integration for Eclipse (update-site) - http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/
 Selected SonarQube Eclipse Integration and SonarQube Java Configuration helper)

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SonarQube Integration for Eclipse 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Apache Apache HttpClient OSGi bundle 4.3.2 (org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient 4.3.2) requires 'package org.apache.commons.logging [1.1.0,1.2.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SonarQube Integration for Eclipse 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE)
    To: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [4.3.2]

Can any one please suggest whats missing here

Comment: If my feeling is correct, your issue might relate to the following thread on the SonarLint Google Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarlint/CseUAN-pJnw/GRuKQDJFCAAJ

Comment: thats not my issue to relate

Comment: @user3123934, have you found out the solution?